# How to update a progress bar from a method inside SwingWorker

Tags: java, swing, swingworker, jprogressbar

I'm trying to update a progress bar and I can't do it. My code is something like this:

```
public class MyWorker extends SwingWorker<Void, Void> {

    public Void doInBackground(){
        howMany=Integer.parseInt(textField.getText());
        String result=longMethod(howMany);
        label.setText("Hello, you have "+result);
 }
}

        public class Event implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        label2.setText("Whatever");     
        button.setEnabled(false);
        myWorer.addPropertyChangeListener(this);
        myWorker.execute();
    }

    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent event){
        if("progress".equals(event.getPropertyName())){
           int currentPercent = (int)event.getNewValue();
            progressBar.setValue(currentPercent);
        }
    }
}
```

So I can't use `setProgress` in `doInBackground` since the updating is made by `longMethod()` which is the method containing a big slow loop, placed in another class. I've made something similar passing from that method a variable to the class which contains the `JFrame` and then offering the possibility to see that progress if you click another button.

I don't know if there is some way of making that button (or text field) refresh itself every X seconds without clicking it or a way to use the `setProgress` from the method `longMethod()`

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is some way for `longMethod` to return progress information.

You could, for example, create a simple `interface` which you could pass to `longMethod` which would, when it knows, update the progress...

```
public interface ProgressMonitor {
    /**
     * Passes the progress of between 0-1
     */
    public void progressUpdated(double progress);
}
```

Then in your `doInBackground` method, you would pass an instance of the `ProgressMonitor` to the `longMethod`

```
public class MyWorker extends SwingWorker<Integer, Integer> {
    public Integer doInBackground(){
        // It would be better to have obtained this value before
        // doInBackground is called, but that's just me...
        howMany=Integer.parseInt(textField.getText());
        String result=longMethod(howMany, new ProgressMonitor() {
            public void progressUpdated(double progress) {
                setProgress((int)(progress * 100));
            }
        });
        //label.setText("Hello, you have "+result);
        publish(result);
        return result;
    }

    protected void process(List<Integer> chunks) {
        label.setText("Hello, you have "+chunks.get(chunks.size() - 1));
    }
}
```

This is esstenially an example of the [observer pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/observer-pattern.html)

Now, if you can't modify `longMethod`, then you have no means by which you can update the progress,  because you have no way of knowing what the `longMethod` is doing...

Answer (score -1):

If there is a way to pass the Progress bar to the SwingWorker, then the SwingWorker would have a reference to that progress bar and be able to update it.

Comment: I can update it already from the SwingWorker with setProgress(), the thing is that I want to do it from the method longMethod() inside the SwingWorker.