# How to change value of progress bar and label?

Tags: java, swing, event-dispatch-thread

The `JLabel` and `JProgressBar` do not change their value, only when the method ends.

```
this.desSave.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        DownloadXml();
    }
});

private void DownloadXml() throws Exception {
    Integer a = 456;
    int value = (1000 / a) - 1;
    this.numDes.setText("0" + "/" + a);
    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
        saveXml(ligas.get(i),i,path);
        this.numDes.setText(i + "/" + a); //this is a jlabel
        this.progressbar.setValue(value * i); //jprogressbar
    }
}

private void SaveXml(String xml,int a,String path) throws IOException {
}
```

Comment: Use a SwingWorker, it's progress and PropertyChange support

Comment: You should use a Thread.

Comment: For [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24835638/issues-with-swingworker-and-jprogressbar/24835935#24835935), [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15199091/progress-bar-java/15199220#15199220), [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24945292/how-to-update-a-progress-bar-from-a-method-inside-swingworker/24946032#24946032)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're blocking the event dispatch thread, which is preventing it from updating the UI. You could use a `Thread`, but Swing is a single threaded API, meaning that updates should only be made to UI from within the context of the event dispatching thread.

You could use a `SwingWorker`, which will allow you to execute your long running process in a background thread, but which has support for synchronising updates to the UI safely.

Together with its `progress` and `PropertyChange` support, it becomes easy to manage, for example.

```
public class Worker extends SwingWorker<Object, Object> {

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground() throws Exception {

        // The download code would go here...
        for (int index = 0; index < 1000; index++) {

            int progress = Math.round(((float)index / 1000f) * 100f);
            setProgress(progress);

            Thread.sleep(10);

        }

        // You could return the down load file if you wanted...
        return null;

    }
}
```

The "progress pane"

```
public class ProgressPane extends JPanel {

    private JProgressBar progressBar;

    public ProgressPane() {

        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        progressBar = new JProgressBar();

        add(progressBar);

    }

    public void doWork() {

        Worker worker = new Worker();
        worker.addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
                if ("progress".equals(evt.getPropertyName())) {
                    progressBar.setValue((Integer) evt.getNewValue());
                }
            }

        });

        worker.execute();

    }

}
```

You can use the `publish`/`process` support to and updates to the EDT, the `PropertyChange` support or the worker's done method to get the result of the worker when it's done safely, from within the EDT